# A relationship in a UML class diagram

Tags: databases, database-theory

I am investigating a small database in a paper:
[image]

Each line is a selling record. For instance, Line 2 expresses that `Store 100 in Week 383 sold Product 653; for this selling, the move was 16 and the price was 2.19, thus the profit was 16*2.19*2=7.01` (the other columns are not very important).

The authors then show a UML class diagram as follows:
[image]

What I cannot understand (and is not explained in the paper) is the relationship between `OnSaleKey` and `DetergentKey`. Could anyone tell me what it is about in a UML diagram language?

Comment: A draft version of the original paper can be found here: http://alfa.di.uminho.pt/~jacome/down/ase14.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have many sales of the same product in the same store and in the same week. Also, a detergent can be sold in different weeks in different stores.

This means that you have to create a class Sale, that associates an OnSaleKey to a DetergentKey.

The Sale class is an association class.

From [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) you can find an explanation:

> An association may be refined to have its own set of features; that
>   is, features that do not belong to any of the connected classifiers
>   but rather to the association itself. Such an association is called an
>   association class. It is both an association, connecting a set of
>   classifiers and a class, and as such could have features and might be
>   included in other associations.
>
> An association class can be seen as an association that also has class
>   properties, or as a class that also has association properties.
>
> An association class is shown as a class symbol attached to the
>   association path by a dashed line. The association path and the
>   association class symbol represent the same underlying model element,
>   which has a single name. The association name may be placed on the
>   path, in the class symbol, or on both, but they must be the same name.

In this case it is easier to think about the Sale class as a table in a database that associates an id from OnSaleKey to an id from DetergentKey.